# How to get data between a string and |

Tags: php, regex

I have the following string :

```
Name=Joe|LastName=Doe|City=NY|Country=US|Currency=$|Phone=0123456789|Adress=null
```

I would like for example retreive the phone number so `0123456789`

Here is what I'v done :

```
Phone=(.*)|
```

https://regex101.com/r/4nlrsW/2

And I would like to use it in PHP :

```
preg_match('Phone=(.*)|', $mystring, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Other than the fact that you need to escape `|` in your regex, what is wrong with what you have?

Comment: Use `'/Phone=\K[^|]+/'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note:

- `preg_match` regex string literal should include regex delimiters, e.g. `/`
- To get the substring out of the match, you should at least use a capturing group, or use [`\K` operator](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html)
- `|` is a special regex metacharacter and should be escaped if used outside of a character class
- `.*` is a *greedy* pattern and matches as many chars other than line break chars as possible.

You may use

```
'~Phone=\K[^|]+~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rLbRYo/1), details:

- `Phone=` - a literal string
- `\K` - match reset operator discarding all text matched so far from the match memory buffer
- `[^|]+` - 1 or more chars other than `|` (`|` does not have to be escaped inside a character class).

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/lBNSE):

```
$text='Name=Joe|LastName=Doe|City=NY|Country=US|Currency=$|Phone=0123456789|Adress=null';
if (preg_match('~Phone=\K[^|]+~', $text, $match)) {
    echo $match[0];
}
```